# How to handle onClick on a RelativeLayout that is part of HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, touch-event, horizontalscrollview

I have RelativeLayouts in HorizontalScrollView. When a user clicks on one of the layouts (or any of its childs) I need to change the background color of the certain RelativeLayout and get its ID for further process. I saw this might be done with DuplicateParentState or with onTouchEvent. Which way is recommended?

My XML file after editing the XML file as proposed:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <youme.appyoume.com.ExDialog>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="text" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            </youme.appyoume.com.ExDialog>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks,
  Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the custom class youve created in your xml you just use the entire root name of the object. So for instance if you have a class in

```
com.your.package.customButton
```

you would write in your xml

```
<RelativeLayout
   ...layoutstuff config>

  <com.your.package.customButton
    ...customButton layout config/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if your subclassing a relativelayout you would use it like this

```
<youme.appyoume.com.ExDialog
    ...layout setup stuff>

    <Button
     ...button setup stuff
    />

 </youme.appyoume.com.ExDialog>
```

Comment: I have edited my question to show the XML  after the change. I added the tag but I get an error: "Binary XML file error line #1: error inflating class"

Comment: Im guessing your using a subclass of a relativelayout so I will rewrite my second answer to show how youd use your class instead.

Comment: Yeah occasionally when I use that I get the same error as well. You must have a typo in your file path or something

Answer (score 0):

You could always assign a tag to it for future reference using setTag and getTag and just use setOn Click Listener and put what ever you need to happen in there

Comment: The problem I see is that I even don't get the activity's onClick called when pressing some of the objects. Do I need to define Clickable and a method onClick for all of them?

Comment: No you don't have to set the onclick for all of them. You can subclass relativelayout and override the onclick there to do you're color change.

Comment: Then use your subclass instead of the normal relative layout

Comment: How do I associate the subclass with the XML file?